# ggplot to sync y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

i'd like to produce two histogram on the same scale y-axis using `gridExtra` here is my attempt:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

dat_url <- 'https://gender-pay-gap.service.gov.uk/viewing/download-data/2019'
dat <- read_csv(dat_url) 

p1 <- dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMedianHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMedianHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = DiffMedianHourlyPercent<=0),
                 breaks=seq(-100,100, by=2)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none")

p2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMeanHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMeanHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = DiffMeanHourlyPercent<=0),
                 breaks=seq(-100,100, by=2)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
p2 <- p2 + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
p2

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

as seen from the plot y-axis are not to the same scale... [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to try a `facet_wrap()` approach. Your code is creating additional data in order to create different plots. You can set up an optimal pipeline in order to reshape the data based on the variables you want and get the desired plot with the common y-axis. Here the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
#Data
dat_url <- 'https://gender-pay-gap.service.gov.uk/viewing/download-data/2019'
dat <- read_csv(dat_url) 

#Plot
G1 <- dat %>% 
  select(c(DiffMedianHourlyPercent,DiffMeanHourlyPercent)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  #Filter
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(between(value,-100,100)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = value<=0),
                 breaks=seq(-100,100, by=2)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_x')
```

Output:

[image]